# MySql queries slow after dropping database with .NET

Tags: mysql, .net, database, c#-4.0

I seem to be having a problem with the MySql connector in .NET.

I'm doing unit tests on my database interface back-end. Part of the test is to drop the database so that the entire database can be re-initialized to a default setting. Here is what my test looks like normally:

[Imgur Image (Since I don't have the rep yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sihQe.jpg)

The drop code is simply:

```
        string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[APPCONFIG_SCHEMA_CONNECTION_NAME].ConnectionString;

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS securitydata;";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

If I manually drop the database using the workbench and modify the the test by commenting out the drop, the tests are literally 50x faster than they were:

[Imgur Image of fast test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uoIZ.jpg)

This is all using the MySql Connector/NET from the NuGet package available on NuGet.org. I've tested this on my development (local) machine running MySql 5.6.24 and the eventual production machine using MySql 5.5.41.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in case anybody runs into the same thing. Here is how I had the TestInitialize:

```
        [TestInitialize]
        public void InitializeTest(TestContext c)
        {
#if DEBUG
            SecurityDatabase.DropDatabase();
#endif
            _database = new SecurityDatabase();
        }
```

Which was a misunderstanding on my part. `TestInitialize` is run for **every test**, not once when the test class is set up. I had forgotten about the `ClassInitialize` attribute, which runs once per `TestClass`. The modified code is:

```
        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void InitializeClass(TestContext c)
        {
#if DEBUG
            SecurityDatabase.DropDatabase();
#endif
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void InitializeTest()
        {
            _database = new SecurityDatabase();
        }
```

Now the tests behave properly, and since the database is only dropped once per test set, exposed some issues in some of my test cases.